# Switching a Circuit on/off with a MOSFET

Tags: gpio, pi-2, rpi.gpio, pi-gpio

I have have a simple circuit that I want to drive with a raspberry pi GPIO pin and I want to use a MOSFET to control the circuit. My circuit will be using about 3-5v and 2-3a.

I'm planning on using a IRLB3034PBF. Or maybe an IRF510 since that is available in a physical store at RadioShack.

**From what I've read and tried to understand from the datasheets, my 3-5v and 2-3a should be well below the limit of either... But can I drive it with a raspberry pi or arduino?? And am I correct in my reading of the datasheets?**

Also, in a lot of diagrams I've seen for this type of circuit online, there is a resistor from the Gate to the GPIO pin. Why is that?

Edit: From what I can tell on the datasheets, Vgs is only limited to +-20V for either. How can one tell that the IRF510 would be a bad fit? Is it because the max Gate Threshold Voltage is 4V which is greater than 3V3?

Thank you for all of your help everyone! I'm a software guy so this low level circuit stuff is still new to me.

Comment: The IRF510 might not be a good choice to be driven directly from a Pi's GPIO pin. 3V3 is a little too low as V_GS for your desired drain current. The listed max threshold voltage V_GS is 4V, so any particular IRF could have a threshold of up to 4V - and therefore not be sufficiently saturated at 3V3.

Comment: I just posted a question about a different MOSFET.  Take a look here and please answer or comment:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72884/rpi3b-mosfet-for-directly-switching-24-volt-loads-any-reason-not-to-use-the

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment, so here's a very short answer.
If your MOSFET is too 'stiff', you can add a BJT driver, i.e. a bipolar transistor stage that will accept the GPIO input and will pilot the fet in the second stage with the required voltage.

See the answer to this question for a schematic:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169211/using-npn-bjt-with-a-p-channel-mosfet-to-switch-3-3v-to-24v

2N3904 and 2N2222 are 'jellybean' transistors: they are everywhere and cost a fraction of a penny.

Or you could use a "logic level MOSFET". User mindcrime in his/her answer here

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/is-it-safe-to-drive-a-mosfet-from-an-output-pin-of-a-microcontroller

suggests an IR**L**540, and explains what you should be looking for in the datasheet:

> The big thing is to look in the data sheet and check the
>   VGS(threshold) value and look at the graph that shows current flow vs
>   VGS. If the VGS(threshold) is like 1.8V or 2.1V or so, and the "knee
>   of the curve" on the graph is at around 5 volts, you basically have a
>   logic-level MOSFET.